# Timeseries forecasting in Python with datetime indexes

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, time-series, gaussian

I'm trying to forecast a time serie using both SVR and GP. 
The time serie is in fact a `pandas.Series` with `pandas.DatetimeIndex` as indexes.

Both of the algorithms are implemented in scikit-learn. Whereas SVR actually accepts to predict with X axis after a modification :

```
train_size = 100
svr = GridSearchCV(SVR(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.001), cv=5,
               param_grid={"C": [1e0, 1e1, 1e2, 1e3],
                           "gamma": np.logspace(-2, 2, 5)})

# Chose train_size items randomly in the data to predict
data_train = ts.sample(n=train_size)
data_train_y = data_train.values
data_train_x = (data_train.index.values).reshape(train_size, 1)

t0 = time.time()
svr.fit(data_train_x, data_train_y)
svr_fit = time.time() - t0
print("SVR complexity and bandwidth selected and model fitted in %.3f s"
  % svr_fit)

sv_ratio = svr.best_estimator_.support_.shape[0] / train_size
print("Support vector ratio: %.3f" % sv_ratio)


min_date = min(ts.index.values)
max_date = max(ts.index.values) + np.timedelta64('1','D')

X_plot = pd.date_range(min_date, max_date, freq='H')
X_plot = X_plot.to_series()
X_plot = X_plot.reshape([len(X_plot),1])

t0 = time.time()
y_svr = svr.predict(X_plot)
svr_predict = time.time() - t0
print("SVR prediction for %d inputs in %.3f s"
  % (X_plot.shape[0], svr_predict))
```

Gaussian process doesn't want to deal with it :

```
from sklearn import gaussian_process
gp = gaussian_process.GaussianProcess(theta0=1e-2, thetaL=1e-4, thetaU=1e-1)
gp.fit(data_train_x, data_train_y)
```

It leads to :

```
TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the timestamp data types are unacceptable. They should be converted to float.